# Alternative to JQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Recently searched for an alternative way to mount dom structures in a better manner that the usual jquery's manner. Found this jquery template.

Is this being developed yet? The documentation is broken. It seems that what you find on the web doesn't match with what you have, which makes me think there's some other jquery template out there.

I personnally like to create the dom dynamically, so I found it great!
But as I mentioned before, it seems that don't improve it anymore. Is that correct? If yes, What else do I have that does a similar job of jquery templates?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
by the way, we have 495 questions tagged with jquery-templates. Why only a few people use it? Is it not good enough ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this being developed yet?

No, it's over.

> Why only a few people use it?

Because it's deprecated.

Checkout [`mustache`](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) instead.

Comment: I think a little search would figure this out. Woulndt it? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since a lot of people are coming to this question I wanted to point out that I went with [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) because it's so much easier to render/create html and do all kinds of front-end stuff.
So far I love angular and I wish I could have known it earlier. It's such a handy tool.
There's also [React](https://github.com/facebook/react)

For those that only wants a drop-in solution I think mustache is still the right way to go.